# SQL query including multiple format with hyphen

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need help with coming up with all invalid tax-id from the table below WHERE county is USA. (Valid formats are strictly 'XXXXXXXXX', 'XX-XXXXXXX', 'XXX-XX-XXXX' (ALL numeric values)

so if column has null value, alpha numeric, I should be able to get back in the result.  Anything other than the above format should be in the output.

i wrote the below, but its not giving me what I am looking for.

```
SELECT 
   AT.ACCOUNTID, 
   AT.TAXID, 
   AT.COUNTRY 
FROM 
   ACCOUNT_TABLE AT
WHERE 
   AT.TAXID NOT LIKE '__-_______%'
   AND AT.TAXID NOT LIKE '_________'
   AND AT.TAXID NOT LIKE '___-__-____'
   AND AT.TAXID IS NULL
   AND AT.COUNTRY = 'USA'
```

Results:

```
ACCOUNTID   TAXID   COUNTRY
70656   N/A           NULL
69163   FOREIGN       GBR
474 REP GERMANY       DEU
66295   12-1234567    IRL
69442   660-535408    USA
1441    CANADIAN      NULL
70135   999999999     NULL
1369    OFFSHORE      CAN
1467    123456789     JE
1473    123-45-6789   FRA
255894  N/A           GBR
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The answers are completely different. mysql <> sqlserver.

Comment: Why do you have a `%` in the first pattern? Can the string really be any length?

Comment: Which one are you using?  `sql server` or `mysql`?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**MYSQL**</kbd>

The following regexes need to be used in your query:

```
'^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]+$' to match 'XXX-XX-XXXX'

'^[0-9]+$' to match 'XXXXXXXXX'

'^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]+$' to match 'XX-XXXXXXX'
```

So, here's the full query:

```
SELECT 
  AT.ACCOUNTID, 
  AT.TAXID, 
  AT.COUNTRY 
FROM ACCOUNT_TABLE AT
WHERE AT.COUNTRY = 'USA'
AND (
        AT.TAXID IS NULL 
        OR   
        (
          AND AT.TAXID REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]+$' = 0
          AND AT.TAXID REGEXP '^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]+$' = 0
          AND AT.TAXID REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' = 0
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server you could use `replace` and `isnumeric` to do the checks on the digits. Note that some conditions should be combined with a logical `or` instead of `and`:

```
select at.accountid, at.taxid, at.country 
from   account_table at
where  (  not isnumeric(replace(at.taxid, '-', ''))
       or (    at.taxid not like '__-_______'
           and at.taxid not like '_________'
           and at.taxid not like '___-__-____'
          )
       or at.taxid is null)
and    at.country = 'usa'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT 
   AT.ACCOUNTID, 
   AT.TAXID, 
   AT.COUNTRY 
FROM 
   ACCOUNT_TABLE AT
WHERE  AT.COUNTRY = 'USA' and (
   AT.TAXID NOT LIKE '__-_______%'
   OR AT.TAXID NOT LIKE '_________'
   OR AT.TAXID NOT LIKE '___-__-____'
   OR AT.TAXID IS NULL );
```

Answer (score 0):

The below worked! Thanks to all who tried.

```
select AT.ACCOUNTID, AT.TAXID, AT.COUNTRY from account_table at
where AT.COUNTRY = 'USA'
and (AT.TAXID IS NULL
or TRANSLATE(AT.TAXID, '012345678' , '999999999' ) NOT IN ('999999999', '99-       9999999', '999-99-9999'))
```